# Browser Console Errors not affecting client side behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am getting the below browser console errors in my `asp` application. The client side scripts are all working properly.

However, i am wondering if these errors can give me problems in future or can i just ignore them?

**These are the errors i am getting:**

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on these errors and whether they are indeed critical and must be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is errors of `Firebug`, not your `asp` application, just ignore them.

It seems caused by `firebug` conflict with other firefox plugins.